# how to make administrative.land_parcel geometry visible under zoom out

Tags: google-maps, zooming

I am using the Google Maps API.

Lots adjoining my property are visible at zoom level 18 and 17, but not 16.  I would like to keep the property lines visible at slightly lower zoom levels.  Can someone point me to code that changes the zoom threshold for displaying this geometry?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @BKFC. Could you clarify what app you're using? This may help the community assist you.

Comment: I'm using Firefox and Chrome on a Mac with OS 10.12.6.  I'm not an API expert, but I've figured out how to change the color of the property lines.  Declaring them 'visible' doesn't prevent them from disappearing when going from zoom 17 to 16.

Comment: What I meant was -- My first guess is that you're using Google Maps API, but your question doesn't state that. This would be the first step in getting help with your question.

Comment: Sorry - yes, Google Maps API.

Comment: API follows below. The result is that the property boundary lines do come out in red, but specifying 'visible' has no effect: when zooming out past 16, the boundary lines disappear.                                                                                                     
   "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
    { "visibility" : "on" },
    { "color": "#FF0000" }]
}
    ]
    });

Comment: I'll make the question more general: how do I use API v3 to override the default zoom level for which any element (town, road, etc.) is visible or invisible.  I'm basically looking for the correct syntax and/or an example that does this.